# Unsuccessful customization of Devise generated User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added a username:string attribute to the default Devise generated User model (as well as a form field in the devise new/edit registrations), and it does not successfully make the User's username anything other than nil, but there is no error when submitting either the edit or new form.

```
<div><%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %></div>
```

I created another users controller and gave it strong parameters with the username attribute made accesible, I also made :username accessible through the registrations controller which extends the Devise::RegistrationsController

What is the stand/accepted way to edit your Devise generated User models?

Comment: checkout https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this sanitize method and before action to your application controller:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        [:sign_up, :account_update].each do |action|
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(action).push(:user_name)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Should action just be action, or should it be new or edit if those are the actions I am using?

Comment: Just a before action in your application controller. You should be able to copy and paste that code

Answer (score 0):

According to [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) this should work for you:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up, :update) << :username
  end
end
```

NOTE: this should be done in the Application Controller.

Hope it helps,.